# How to put a View in the back of the Navigation Bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one `View` which I want to put in the whole screen, ie.. by making the `status bar` (top bar) and `navigation bar` (bottom bar) translusent and putting some portion of the view behind it. I tried the using the flags :

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

But they just hide them, and on touching these flags get cleared. It is understandable that `android OS` wants user to always have the `navigation bar` and that is why it is showing them again, but isn't there a way to just show our view behind the navigation bar.

I manage to put my layout behind the status bar using

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
```

But still, how can I put my view behind Navigation bar too.
Also I am developing the app for API level 14 and above, so I cant use, `IMMERSIVE_STICKY` or `IMMERSIVE` mode. Any Suggestions will be appreciated.